How to prioritize and display correct UI for multiple actions triggered by the same input?
In my Unity game, the "Interact" action is used for multiple tasks like opening doors and grabbing/dropping objects. However, there are scenarios where the player has an object in their hands and a door in front of them. Pressing "Interact" triggers both actions simultaneously (dropping the object and opening the door). I want the first valid action to be executed, and any subsequent actions should be ignored.
I managed to solve the input issue by passing an additional parameter with a property isHandled. The first action that processes the event sets this flag to true, preventing further actions from processing:
public UnityEvent<EventState, bool> OnInteract = new UnityEvent<EventState, bool>();

The issue I’m facing now is the UI: the game displays both "Press E to open the door" and "Press E to drop" at the same time, which is confusing for players. I need to prioritize the correct UI prompt, ensuring that only the action that will be executed is shown.
One idea I have is to trigger a fake input event with a special flag to determine which action would be executed without actually performing it. If the action can proceed (i.e., it hasn’t been handled yet), then its UI prompt would be shown.
Is there a better or more efficient way to ensure only the correct UI prompt is displayed based on action priority? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

How have you currently implemented your contextual UI display and input handling? The more we know about your current setup, the better we can advise on how to adapt it without an undue amount of re-building.

I have a "command" queue for each unit. As each command finishes (i.e. travel leg), the unit pulls another command from the queue, if there is one. In the event the unit is ordered to "halt", the current action is halted and the queue is cleared. A queued command can be ignored if not right for the current "state" (e.g. "captured"). The next obvious action to queue is: "Try to escape" for say 10 minutes. Then, etc. Any time a command is submitted for a unit, it starts the dequeing process; if it hasn't already. "Polling" involves (just) keeping idle units busy.

Unreal engine handles this situation by only allowing one blueprint script to handle a given input, at which point it is either handled and consumed or passed to the next script(a checkbox allows both). The input scripts are ordered by the order they are added for capture, very rarely is any external timing control needed.

Just to flush out @DMGregory's comment.
You have several design decisions to make, the first is to decide if it is possible to interact with multiple objects at once, in general the answer is probably no (that only one on object can be interacted with at once). It is possible to design a system that allows multiple interactions, but to keep this answer simple I will assume only one interaction is allowed.
However in game the player may encounter a situation where there are multiple interact-able things (per your question) you might have a held item and encounter a door. You need to design/decide what happens in such cases, for example you may choose:

To state that one action has absolute priority - i.e. if you are holding something you can only interact with that item - no other interactions are possible.
You may decide that it is an error, and as such tell the player there are multiple interactions possible and that they either have to "un-wield" the item or move away from the door before any action can be taken.
You may present a menu and allow the player to choose which action to take.
If there are never more than 2 actions possible, it may make sense to have two interact keys (interact with held vs world item).

Whatever you decide, it should be clear to the player what will happen when they press the interact button (with the possible exception of hidden interactions) hence your code should decide in advance of the player interacting, what action will happen and provide a hint (if necessary) to indicate to the player what will happen.
This means that at any point in the game, you need to:

Scan for all possible interactions.
If there are multiple actions, prioritize and select the highest priority.
Store/Record the highest priority action.
Display a hint to the player (if necessary).

Then when/if the player presses the interact key, you don't need to scan the actions at that time you just execute the stored action.
